# How haproxy frontend not 443 port balance backend 443?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

my haproxy configuration is:

```
# Configuration for 678da17a-5c8f-4d2b-9431-f3019aae9726
global
    daemon
    user nobody
    group haproxy
    log /dev/log local0 debug alert
    log /dev/log local1 notice alert
    maxconn 2000
    stats socket /var/lib/neutron/lbaas/v2/678da17a-5c8f-4d2b-9431-f3019aae9726/haproxy_stats.sock mode 0666 level user

defaults
    log global
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend 8e85521c-f92b-401a-a72f-9f3d9dbd9deb
    option tcplog
    bind 123.44.44.44:5200
    mode tcp
    default_backend 46a948a1-1043-437d-83d0-e25acf0c94fd

backend 46a948a1-1043-437d-83d0-e25acf0c94fd
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server 9add0118-0255-4ee3-998a-875fb251624b 123.23.23.23:443 weight 1
```

I want to configure frontend using 5200 port to access backend server 123.23.23.23:443.
But when i request https://123.44.44.44:5200, the request change to https://123.44.44.44/index.html. It leads to request failure.
Why happens that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the server software on **9add0118-0255-4ee3-998a-875fb251624b** send a redirect.

You should tell the server software on **9add0118-0255-4ee3-998a-875fb251624b** to redirect to `123.44.44.44:5200` instead of there own IP.

You can see what the server send back in haproxy debug frontend mode.
`haproxy -d <OPTIONAL_MORE_OPTIONS>`

Doc: [Starting HAProxy](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/management.html#3)